# Asynchronous Multithreading: Error compiling shader. (libgdx)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, libgdx

I'm writing an application with the libgdx api for Android, and I'm running into issues concerning changing states and multithreading.

---

What I initially want is two asynchronous threads running at the same time, one being the game **render** thread, and the other being the game **logic** thread. I then want to be able to change the state of the game, which changes the update/render methods on their respective objects. Obviously, the render thread is running per frame (which is taken care of by libgdx already). This is my code modeling my attempt to do so:

```
public final class StateManager {

private static State gameState = State.START;

private static StateObject stateObject = new StartScreen();

private static final Object syncObjectUpdate = new Object();
private static final Object syncObjectRender = new Object();

public static void update(float elapsedTime){

    if (!stateObject.isCreated){

        //pause this thread until render thread stops
        synchronized(syncObjectUpdate) {
            try {
                // Calling wait() will block this thread until another thread
                // calls notify() on the object.
                syncObjectUpdate.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {} // Happens if someone interrupts your thread.
        }

        //once the render thread stops-

        stateObject.dispose();

        switch (gameState){

            //note: creating a new object here sets isCreated to true,
            //so the if statements gets called only once per state change.
            case START:
                stateObject = new StartScreen();
                break;
            case GAME:
                stateObject = new GameScreen();
                break;
            case LOADING:
                //stateObject = new LoadingScreen();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.print("ERROR IN STATE!");
                break;
        }//end switch


        //-change the state and resume render thread
        //what if this happens before wait? surround in while loop?
        synchronized(syncObjectRender) {
            syncObjectRender.notify();
        }


    }//end if

    stateObject.update(elapsedTime);
}

public static void render(){
    stateObject.render();

    //if update thread is waiting
    if (MyGdxGame.logicThread.getState() == Thread.State.WAITING){

        //then resume that one,
        synchronized(syncObjectUpdate) {
            syncObjectUpdate.notify();
        }

        // and pause this one
        synchronized(syncObjectRender) {
            try {
                syncObjectRender.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
        }

    }//end if

}//end render

public static void changeState(State state){
    stateObject.isCreated = false;
    gameState = state;
}

public static void dispose(){
    stateObject.dispose();
}

public static void resize(int width, int height){
    stateObject.resize(width, height);
}

public static void pause(){
    stateObject.pause();
}

public static void resume(){
    stateObject.resume();
}

}//class
```

This runs well, until I call changeState(), and it throws the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(19094): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error compiling shader
```

- I **THINK** this happened because stateObject.render() got called (which changes the spritebatch and such) while there was no StateObject present.

[BTW, if it isn't clear already, a StateObject is something like a start screen, or game screen, which has a render() and update() method inside that are called by two different threads. Also, I wrote this program before without multithreading, and the state changing mechanism worked perfectly.]

---

Here's my thought process:

**1.** When I change the state, the update thread gets the notification. This pauses the update thread. (Render is still running)

**2.** When the render thread sees that the update thread is paused, it resumes the update thread and pauses the render thread. This is so the stateObject.render() method doesn't get called before it tries to call render() on something that is disposed.

**3.** At this point, the update thread is notified to start up again, so it disposes of the StateObject and creates a new one.

**4.** Now that a new state object is initialized, stateObject.render() should have no problem. It then resumes the render thread. Both threads should be running, and peace in the universe is restored.

Now there's obviously something wrong with my implementation or that logic, because I'm getting that error. So... why?

Any help is greatly appreciated. If something isn't clear, let me know in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: This question isn't getting much activity, and I doubt I stumped the community, so are there are suggestions to make this question better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through hours of experimenting, I was able to solve this by putting the switch-case in the render method, and deleting the line `stateObject.dispose();`. That's it, no waiting on threads and locking objects. This now calls the appropriate render method for the state without issues of changing the spritebatch (because its in the same OpenGL thread). Deleting the dispose method means that whenever I attempt to change the state, the update method always has something to update.

This is rather a work around because changing the sate is now handed in the render method, but the performance impact is ***very*** minimal.

Here are the working render and update methods with the changes (same class):

```
public static void update(float elapsedTime){
    stateObject.update(elapsedTime);
}

public static void render(){
    stateObject.render();

    if (!stateObject.isCreated){

        switch (gameState){

            case START:
                stateObject = new StartScreen();
                break;
            case GAME:
                stateObject = new GameScreen();
                break;
            case LOADING:
                //stateObject = new LoadingScreen();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.print("ERROR IN STATE!");
                break;
        }//end switch

    }//end if

}//end render
```

I hope this helps someone!